# Is there any way to find the logged hours in particular day by you in JIRA?

Tags: jira

Is there any way to check how many our you have logged today in JIRA?

I don't have admin or super user access in JIRA, I am a programmer and am assigned sprint tasks, so my permissions could be limited. I don't find any option to check how many total hours I logged today in different tasks.

One way I guess could be to go to the tasks and check the history, but that is useless because the main problem is that only that I want to know the tasks on which I logged hours.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the most recent versions of Jira, the following should work for you...

Go on navbar -> Issues -> Search for Issue -> Advance Search

```
Today:

worklogDate = endOfDay() and worklogAuthor = currentUser


Specific date:

worklogDate = "2015/07/10" and worklogAuthor = currentUser
```

This would filter all issue to only issues that you logged your work on.

Also you may save the issue search for later reference.

Note: Valid formats include: 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'YYYY-MM-DD', or a period format e.g. '-5d', '4w 2d'.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But it lists all the issues on which I logged hours but is there any way it can show me total hours logged? Because to know that I will have to go to each story and have see the history. I was looking for something that can give me total hours I logged on particular day

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below navigation

Go in your project -> Left Menu select the Reports -> In All Reports -> Go into the Time Reports -> select the start date and end date

Now, you find out the logged by you.

Also, there is direct link but you need to change based on your jira domain and project

https://jira_domain/plugins/servlet/ac/timereports/timereports-report?project.key=jira_project_key&project.id=jira_project_code

Please let me know if still anything else you need.